# Is select_related() still needed after defining only() in django query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

select_related is used so whenever a defined foreign key accessed, it will be included in the first query and won't issue another query to db. But I have a case when only few fields are needed. Here is the example

```
class PMapKomoditi(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    komoditi_fk = models.ForeignKey(PMastKomoditi, models.RESTRICT, db_column='id_komoditi')
    kd_komoditi = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    nm_komoditi = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    // ...


class PMastKomoditi(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    // ...
```

I only need *kd_komoditi* & *komoditi_fk* properties, so I do query the following:

```
my_query = PMapKomoditi.objects.select_related(
    'komoditi_fk'
).Only(
    'kd_komoditi',
    'komoditi_fk'
)
```

Do I need to include the select_related or it's already covered with only()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `only` will not make a join like `select_related` does. So you cannot replace `select_related` by `only`. Furthermore the field referred to by `select_related` must also be part of the call to `only` if you are using it and cannot be deferred. You can also add related fields to the `only` call if you want to select only few of the related models fields.

Moving further when in doubt one should simply check the SQL query generated by the ORM:

```
my_query = PMapKomoditi.objects.select_related(
    'komoditi_fk'
).only(
    'kd_komoditi',
    'komoditi_fk'
)

print(my_query.query) # Performs an INNER JOIN


my_query2 = PMapKomoditi.objects.only(
    'kd_komoditi',
    'komoditi_fk'
)

print(my_query2.query) # No INNER JOIN
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question!  And I don't know the answer!  But you can find out by using the "query" attribute of your query set.

```
my_query = PMapKomoditi.objects.select_related('komoditi_fk').only('kd_komoditi','komoditi_fk')
print(my_query.query)

test_query = PMapKomoditi.objects.only('kd_komoditi','komoditi_fk')
print(test_query.query)
```

That will tell you what's going on "under the covers".